# Send JSON Object in POST request from Android Volley receive java restful webservices

Tags: java, json, rest, post, android-volley

I want small example to send JSON object in POST request from android volley and it has to receive Java Restful Webservices

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following working sample code. Hope this helps!

```
        ...   
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Title", "VolleyApp Android Demo");
            jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
            jsonBody.put("Date", "2015/08/26");
            requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(1, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    textView.setText(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    textView.setText(error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return String.format("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                                requestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            queue.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Moreover, can you clarify what does `it has to receive Java Restful Webservices` mean? My above request receives **String** value.

Comment: we are sending json object through POST request in android volley i want to get same json object in restful webservices in java

Comment: So, try my code, that's POST request with JSONObject as a body

Comment: @venkatasivaiah: have my answer worked for your issue yet?